# OpenShift app can't connect to MySQL : JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, openshift

I generated a .war file for my SpringMVC + Maven + Hibernate + MySQL app which was working perfectly fine on localhost and local MySQL database. The way I configure the database is through a WebAppConfig.java file which looks at an application.properties file and retrieves the appropriate information.

Then I created an OpenShift account and deployed that .war file. I added MySQL and PHPMyAdmin cartridges so I can maintain a database. When I try to retrieve information or push to the database through my application I receive this error.

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
>
> **message** Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
>
> **exception** org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

I already added the appropriate information for my database in my properties file so I don't think that is the issue.

**application.properties**

```
#DB
db.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url = jdbc:mysql://{OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:{OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/springmvc
db.username = {OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}
db.password = {OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}

#Hibernate
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
entitymanager.packages.to.scan = org.example.app.model
hibernate.cache.provider_class = org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
```

Note: In my actual code I have the actual OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST and OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT values not those placeholders!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to actually answer this question.

I just want to clarify once again that using the 'OPENSHIFT' variables rather than putting the ACUTAL values in the application.properties fixed the issue.

> db.url = jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}
>
> db.username = ${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}
>
> db.password = ${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure mysql cartridge is up and running; if need be try restarting it. Otherwise, please post your properties file. Also please read the following threads, it may be of help:

https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/hibernate-mysql-connection-failing
https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/mysql-db-stops-responding-after-some-time

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will be sure to add the application.properties file in my original post! I also made sure that the mysql cartridge is in fact up and running.

Comment: Thanks for adding application properties. Please do not use root/pass; instead use the information that was provided to you when mysql cartridge was added or you can use the environment variables: OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME/OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been more clear, in my code I do use what was provided through openshift and NOT root/pass! I just didn't want to post the pass on here I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting to our forums as well:
https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/openshift-app-cant-connect-to-mysql-jdbcconnectionexception-could-not-open

Looks like you'll want to use:
db.username = {OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}
db.password = {OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}

instead of:
db.username = root
db.password = pass

Comment: Sorry, I should've noted that in my original post. I am using what was provided to me by openshift, I'll update the OP!

Answer (score 0):

Missing the $ in the variable names, you can also run it locally very easily to make sure it's just the mysql variables and not a coding error.

Have you checked PHPMyAdmin to make sure MYSQL is up has the database and tables you expect and validate all your sql.

Does WebAppConfig have the proper Spring annotations?  Does it build fully with no errors?  Do your unit tests work?  Do you have all the maven dependencies and versions established?

This has worked for me using OpenStack on all their available java server types.

Comment: Yeah, you're right I was in fact missing that and I added an answer that ended up working for me! Have you added Ehcache to the OpenStack app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why openshift force us to use their environment variables instead of using "localhost:3306" and the actual values for username/password. This is making us very inconvenient. Also, adding this line of code jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}

in my application-context.xml gets a compilation error since spring doesn't recognize these values.