# Not working enviromental variable OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST in a JDBC connection to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsf, openshift

I'm trying to make a basic JDBC connection to MySQL. I deployed application on openshift server (tomcat7, mysql) but I can't connect with my db (I use phpmyadmin to create db and tables). I'am using Spring 3.1 MVC, JSF and Primefaces.

I deployed some time ago a simple java web application and I used a **class conection**:

```
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String host = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST");
        String port = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+host+":"+port+"/demo01";
        String user = "adminujFVYBF";
        String password = "EIyNRbHNBxN_";
```

This time I wanted to use a **jdbc.properties file** with Spring MVC in order to manage the values

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver                                                 
jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT)}/libreriaapp
jdbc.username=adminCnH8p6r
jdbc.password=EhBHSvIqHFAz
```

So I tried unsuccessfully to figure out how can I use environmental variables in the jdbc url in order to get working my db .

**This is my application Context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

   <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

   <bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"         
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}" />              

   <context:component-scan base-package="pe.egcc.eureka.app.layer.controller"/>

  </beans>
```

[**Project Repository**]
https://github.com/cachuan07/libreriaapp [1](https://github.com/cachuan07/libreriaapp)

If anyone can point me in the right direction that'd be great. Sorry for the huge post, it needed a bit of explaining to make it coherent. Hopefully it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: There are inaccuracies between your context file and your error. Is it `${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}` or `$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST`?

Comment: What happens when you `echo $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT`?

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: Are you actually setting environment properties named `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST`?

Comment: I just fowolling examples and the first time works without setting it, I have a similar problem like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204482/openshift-app-cant-connect-to-mysql-jdbcconnectionexception-could-not-open-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HI you can simply write a code like this..

```
try{Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
username=asfksjfjs;

password=sflkaskfjhsjk; 
url="jdbc:mysql://178.360.01:3306/demo01";  
con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);}
```

just copy those port no and host name from your phpmyadmin...

It will work surly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use environment variables in a jdbc.properties file, I don't think they will get parsed (as answered here [Regarding application.properties file and environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263929/regarding-application-properties-file-and-environment-variable)).  You MIGHT be able to use the environment variables right in your xml file if that xml file gets parsed correctly by something that will substitute them (like it does for a standalone.xml or context.xml file)

Answer (score 0):

Activate phpmyadmin, and open it you will find the ip in the header, take it and replace it in the OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST variable, the port is the default mysql : 3306.